# how to add custom additional rpm to existing distro in cobbler?

Tags: linux, kickstart, cobbler

how to add custom rpm to existing distro in cobbler ?

I have tried copying additional rpm packages to the repo URL, but it doesn't pick it from there !

Comment: Which distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Simple copy to the repository isn't enough. You have to recreate repodata. If it's RHEL/CentOS you may use:

```
createrepo -d <path to your YUM repo>
```

if it's system repo, you may have to add -g comps.xml, otherwise PXE installation will fail:

```
createrepo -d -g comps.xml <path to your YUM repo>
```